# Use two job spark to write at the same time in HDFS inside the same repositor

Tags: apache-spark, hdfs

I wonder if it is a bad practice to write (SaveMode.Append) at the same time in the same directory HDFS, with two job Spark.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a bad practice, but in reality in case of jobs chained one after other. The chances are very high that  the output from one job is missed.

Example Spark job1 and job2 writes in hdfs path /user/output. Spark job 3 consumes from the hdfs path.

If you try to build the job chain from oozie there can be situation when Job 1 and Job 3 ran, while JOb 2 ran after Job 3 leading to Job2 data not being consumed from Job 3